# Vhost apache2 configuration

Tags: apache

I am trying to configure virtual host on apache2.

I've checked and the apache2 config file is in sites-enabled

```
root@php-server:/var/www# cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
root@php-server:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 23 18:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jul 23 18:28 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Jul 23 17:51 sitename.com -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/sitename.com
```

This is how my config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@sitename.com
ServerName sitename.com
ServerAlias www.sitename.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sitename.error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sitename.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have the site content on `/var/www/sitename/`

Permission are set correctly on the folder as I can see here:

```
root@php-server:/var/www# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 775 www-data 4096 Jul 23 18:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 May 14 23:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 775 www-data 4096 Jul 23 18:11 sitename
root@php-server:/var/www# pwd
/var/www
```

Also, I have added the domain to digital ocean and pointed it to the correct server.

The domain is hosted on GoDaddy and I have A record there:

```
A   @   XX.XX.XX.XXX    600 seconds
```

Which points to DigitalOcean server.

Do you have some suggestion, how can I solve the problem where I navigate to the page and I can see this

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at somesite.com Port 80
```

Comment: Solve what? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @rickdenhaan Question is updated

Answer (score 0):

It appears that permissions on the folder were wrong.

As it can be seen in the question permissions were set wrong by mistake

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 775 www-data 4096 Jul 23 18:11 sitename
```

When I updated it to correct, it was like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 23 18:11 sitename
```